# Hardening S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We store RPMs required for our deployment in a S3 bucket, we are hosting a yum repo on the bucket to make it easier for updating RPMS.

Currently, our bucket is accessible publicly over the S3 endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com) and open to the world for access as we currently can’t pull down yum packages from a private S3 repo.

We need to harden the security of the Repo bucket to enable authentication based access to S3 over s3.amazonaws.com endpoint. Any suggestion towards it ? Thanks !

```
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Access From QA, dev",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                     
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-repo",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-repo/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "X.X.X.X/32"
                     ]
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-xxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to specifically add an authentication layer take a look at adding a VPC endpoint to the VPC(s) that you want to be able to access your S3 bucket.

Once you have this in place (and added to the route tables) then you can update the bucket policy for your S3 bucket to add a condition to Deny all traffic not from the source VPC endpoint (`aws:sourceVpce`).

The advantage to this approach is that you will not need to make any changes to the servers themselves.

More documentation available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can we use it across 3 different AWS accounts(dev,prod,qa). I meant like creating  VPC endpoints in every account and then add those 3 VPC endpoints to the bucket policy ? So it can be accessed by instances across the 3 accounts.

Comment: Yes of course it would look like `"aws:sourceVpce": ["vpce-1234", "vpce-1235"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer!

Comment: Chris, sorry to trouble, after applying the aws:sourceVpce to the bucket policy, will the instances from the VPC be able to  `curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/dir/file.rpm`, i tested it but the problem is for few users it works and for few it doesnt. Just wanted to check if you have any idea towards it. Thanks again

Comment: Did you add the S3 prefix list to your route tables too? Take a look at the routing section if not https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-routing :)

Comment: Yes the prefix is added to the route table, but i also let the kept internet gateway access entry in the route table. My only doubt can the instances used https connection to fetch the files, when we remove the gateway access, and keep only the prefix list and local ip address range ?

Comment: Hmm that should be fine then, on the ones that fail what is the error?

Comment: `curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file`                       
 access denied `<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>DE0CV4CE51C1BHH5C</RequestId>`

Comment: And thats for different instances inside the same subnet?

Comment: Yes different instances in the same VPC same subnet, we just have 1 VPC 1 subnet. aws ls (cli acess) works for all instances but not via https

Comment: Do you have an upto date bucket policy you could attach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216547/discussion-between-sanjay-m-p-and-chris-williams).